# Xamarin.Android - android:fontFamily doesn't work

Tags: android, xamarin, fonts, xamarin.android

I need to change textView font using android:fontFamily.
The problem is that it gives me errors and I have no idea why

My code:

```
  <TextView
                android:text="Arial font"
                android:textSize="8pt"
                android:fontFamily="@font/arial"
                android:layout_marginTop="4pt"/>
```

I tried literally everything: added Arial.ttf on Assets folder, created a font folder in Assets, tried to change properties, tried to use "arial.ttf" instead of "arial" in android:fontFamily, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 4):

#### Support from only API-26 and above:

- Add your font files in the `Resources/font` directory
- For **API-26+** only support using `android:fontFamily` is fine:

  `android:fontFamily="@font/tastysushi"`

### But... for API 16 through 28+, you need to setup/use the Android Support library

#### Support from API-16+

- Add the `Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat` package (v26 or higher)
- Add the `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat` package (v26+) if you are using `fontFamily` in your AXML layouts (otherwise you can programmatically assign the font family and use `Activity` subclasses)
- Your activity **must** be a subclass of `AppCompatActivity` in order for the layout/AXML-based `app:fontFamily` attribute to work
- Add the font files in the `Resources/font` directory

  ```
   |-Resources
   |  |-font
   |  |  |-tastysushi.ttf
  ```
- Optional, but handy, create a font family xml file in `Resources/font` directory (both `android` and `app` namespaces must be defined)

  ```
  <!-- Resource/font/sushi.xml -->    
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <font-family 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <font
      android:fontStyle="normal"
      android:fontWeight="400"
      android:font="@font/tastysushi"

      app:fontStyle="normal"
      app:fontWeight="400"
      app:font="@font/tastysushi"
  />
  ```

  Note: You can add bold and italic `font` elements also to the font family... and assign each one a different font file from the same family of fonts...
- In top element of your layout file add the `app:` namespace:

  `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`
- Now the `fontFamily` attribute must use to use the `app:` namespace

  `app:fontFamily="@font/sushi"`

Note: The `@font/` can either reference the actual font file or the xml-based font family file

Note: You can also embed the fonts in styles so you do not have to populate each AXML element with the font family...